# Ruby (NoMethodError) because of argument passing

Tags: ruby, function, variables, nomethoderror

I'm trying to assign a function to a variable, it feels so natural to do this:

```
def myfunction(num=3)
    num
end

varfunc = myfunction

puts varfunc # it outputs 3 here, as expected
```

But it's not that easy...

```
puts varfunc(12)
```

Gives me this console Error:

```
test.rb:8:in `<main>': undefined method `varfunc'
for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

How can arguments be passed then? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to assign a function to a variable, it feels so natural to do this:
>
> ```
> def myfunction(num=3)
>   num
> end
>
> varfunc = myfunction
>
> puts varfunc # it outputs 3 here, as expected
> ```

There are several things wrong with this.

First, `myfunction` is not a function, it's a method. Methods aren't objects in Ruby. You can only assign objects to variables, so, since methods aren't objects, you cannot assign them to variables.

Second, you are not assigning the method `myfunction` to the variable `varfunc`, because, as I explained above, you *cannot* do that. You are *calling* the method `myfunction` and assigning its return value to the variable `varfunc`. In Ruby, parentheses are optional for method calls.

Thirdly, even *if* this *did* work as you expect it to, i.e. *if* methods were objects (which they aren't), then the code you showed still shouldn't work the way you see it. *If* `varfunc` *were* a function, then the code would *not* "output 3 here, as expected", because you would expect `varfunc` to be a function, not an integer, and it *should* output something like

```
#<Function:0xdeadbeef4815162342>
```

So, the fact that it *does* output 3 is *not* expected, and in fact clearly tells you that your expectations are *wrong*.

Your logic is inconsistent: on line 5, you assume that leaving off the parentheses will *not* call `myfunction`, but instead reference it, on line 7, you assume that leaving off the parentheses will will *not* reference `varfunc`, but instead call it. That makes no sense.

> But it's not that easy...
>
> ```
> puts varfunc(12)
> ```
>
> Gives me this console Error:
>
> ```
> test.rb:8:in `<main>': undefined method `varfunc'
> for main:Object (NoMethodError)
> ```
>
> How can arguments be passed then? Many thanks.

`varfunc` is a variable, not a method. You can only pass arguments to methods, not to variables. You need to make `varfunc` a method.

There are two ways to approach this. One way would be to make `myfunction` a [`Proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html) object, which is the closest equivalent Ruby has to a "function":

```
myfunction = -> (num=3) { num }

varfunc = myfunction

puts varfunc
# #<Proc:0x007f909285f640@(irb):1 (lambda)>
# *This* is the output you would expect from `puts`ing a "function"

puts varfunc.()
# 3

puts varfunc.(12)
# 12
```

The other possibility would be to use reflection to obtain a [`Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html) wrapper object for the `myfunction` method, using the [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method) method:

```
def myfunction(num=3) num end

varfunc = method(:myfunction)

puts varfunc
# #<Method: Object#myfunction>

puts varfunc.()
# 3

puts varfunc.(12)
# 12
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Quite an illustrative answer. What I was trying to do was something similar to Python, where I can simply assign a function to a variable and just use it as the original function. The thing with the parenthesis is that I read that in Ruby you can leave them out and pass the arguments separated by commas, so I did it.

Comment: Yes, *exactly*, you can leave out the parentheses and it will *still* call the method. The parentheses are optional. However, in your original code, you left the parentheses out *twice*, expected two *different* things to happen: the first time you expected it to act like Python, where parentheses are *required* for calls and leaving them off simply references the function. Whereas the second time, you expected the function to get called *despite* leaving off the parentheses. In other words, the logic within your code was internally inconsistent. Chasing down this inconsistency would have …

Comment: … eventually led you down the path of discovery that I (hopefully) led you down now. This is a general tool for helping you debug your code: verifying your assumptions and your internal logic. In this case, you read that you don't need the parentheses for calling methods (which is correct) and at the same time you assumed it would work like Python (which contradicts what you read).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Your post is quite helpful to me. The thing with the parenthesis, as with the implicit return values, is something I'm battling with when learning ruby, as I see those things as inconsistencies, but, that's the way the language is and they must be there for a reason. Thanks again